# C++ Connect 4 Minimax + Alpha Beta Pruning AI making poor decisions

Tags: c++, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning, connect-four

This post is kind of a follow-up to my last post. To increase the efficiency of a minimax connect-4 AI algorithm, I decided to use alpha-beta pruning. This definitely helped with the long runtime of the program (which I previously believed to be an infinite recursion), but the AI is not working how I want it to.

**The AI is simply choosing the next available empty spot to mark, even if it will lead to a loss.**

I have tried increasing and decreasing the depth level, and made sure the function that checks for a winner actually works. Furthermore, I converted the 2d vector previously used for the board to a 1d vector, and updated other functions accordingly.

Any help on why the AI is behaving the way it is would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isFull(std::vector<char>& grid) { //just checks if no empty spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if(grid[i] == '-') { 
            return false;
        }
    } 

    return true;
}

pair<bool, char> isWinner(std::vector<char>& grid, char aiMark, char hMark) {
    pair<bool, char> temp; // the pair of: whether the game is over, and who won(if any.)
    //'X' if AI wins, 'O' if human wins, '-' if tie/game not over.

    //horizontal check
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 4) {
        if (grid[i] == aiMark && grid[i + 1] == aiMark && 
            grid[i + 2] == aiMark && grid[i + 3] == aiMark) {
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = aiMark;
            return temp;
        }
        else if (grid[i] == hMark && grid[i + 1] == hMark && 
                 grid[i + 2] == hMark && grid[i + 3] == hMark) {
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = hMark;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    //vertical check
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (grid[i] == aiMark && grid[i + 4] == aiMark && 
            grid[i + 8] == aiMark && grid[i + 12] == aiMark) {
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = aiMark;
            return temp;
        } 
        else if (grid[i] == hMark && grid[i + 4] == hMark && 
                 grid[i + 8] == hMark && grid[i + 12] == hMark) {
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = hMark;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    //diagonal checks
    if (grid[0] == aiMark && grid[5] == aiMark && 
        grid[10] == aiMark && grid[15] == aiMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = aiMark;
        return temp;
    } 
    else if (grid[0] == hMark && grid[5] == hMark && 
             grid[10] == hMark && grid[15] == hMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = hMark;
        return temp;
    }

    if (grid[3] == aiMark && grid[6] == aiMark && 
        grid[9] == aiMark && grid[12] == aiMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = aiMark;
        return temp;
    } 
    else if (grid[3] == hMark && grid[6] == hMark && 
             grid[9] == hMark && grid[12] == hMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = hMark;
        return temp;
    }

    if (isFull(grid) == true) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = '-';
        return temp;
    }

    temp.first = false;
    temp.second = '-';
    return temp;
}

int minimax(std::vector<char>& grid, int depth, bool maxim, 
            char aiMark, char hMark, int al, int be) {
    pair<bool, char> result = isWinner(grid, aiMark, hMark);
    
    // result.first will be true if game is over, and result.second is:
    // 'X' if ai wins, 'O' if human wins, '-' if game is not over or if it ends with tie
   
    if (result.first != false || depth == 0) {
        if (result.second == aiMark) {
            return depth; // AI wins (maximizing)
        } 
        else if (result.second == hMark) {
            return -depth; // Human wins (minimizing)
        } 
        else {
            return 0; // Tie or depth = 0
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (maxim == true) {
            int best = INT_MIN;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (grid[i] == '-') { // is space empty?
                    grid[i] = aiMark; // editing board
                    int score = minimax(grid, depth - 1, !maxim, aiMark, hMark, al, be); // call minimax with "new" board
                    best = max(best, score); // update max
                    grid[i] = '-'; // backtrack
                    al = best; // update alpha
                        
                    if (al >= be) {
                        break; // pruning     
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return best; //return max score
        } 
        else {
            int worst = INT_MAX;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (grid[i] == '-') {
                    grid[i] = hMark;
                    int score = minimax(grid, depth - 1, !maxim, aiMark, hMark, al, be);
                    worst = min(worst, score);
                    grid[i] = '-';
                    be = worst;

                    if (be <= al) {  //same as the maximizing player but is minimizing instead
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return worst; //return min score
        }
    }
}

void bestMove(std::vector<char>& grid, char aiMark, char hMark) {
    int best = INT_MIN; //best score for ai
    int finalSpot = -1; //place where ai will put mark
    
    pair<bool, char> result = isWinner(grid, aiMark, hMark); // explained in minimax function comments
    
    if (result.first != false) {
        return; // if game is supposed to be over
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (grid[i] == '-') {
            grid[i] = aiMark;
            int score = minimax(grid, 8, true, aiMark, hMark, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
             
            if (score > best) {
                best = score;
                finalSpot = i; // update best score and best spot
            }
                
            grid[i] = '-'; // backtrack
        }
    }
    
    grid[finalSpot] = aiMark; // AI finally updates grid
    return;
}
```

Comment: Even at depth level 7 and with prunning, number of nodes may exceed 1 million. So optimization of the code is the key. Avoid using containers and minimize use of for loops, use basic data types, use bit level manipulation. See a sample data type used in chess program like GNU chess.

Comment: The problem is not that the code is taking too long to run, it is that the AI is not working the way that the algorithm tells it to.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm can choose a losing move, because in `bestMove()`, you place an `aiMark`, then call `minmax()` with `maxim` set to true which will place a second `aiMark` in a row. The human does not play after the IA does.

Concerning alpha beta, you can also update `alpha` with : `alpha = max(alpha, best)`, and the equivalent way with `beta`. The way you did is not wrong but not optimized, as the value of alpha can drop while it should only raise.

I think the best way to solve your game is to add a transposition table. It is a bit heavy to implement but IA will avoid studying twice the same position. You can first transform your code to a Negamax version which is easy and convenient.